# I am getting a blank duplicate on dragging of an event into Calendar with FullCalendar JQuery Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, calendar, fullcalendar

So I'm getting a strange blank duplicate when dragging a JQuery Draggable onto the Calendar of the FullCalendar JQuery plugin.

It occurs when I add the 'data-event' to one of the events that I am trying to drag into the calendar.

Here is an image of what I am getting: http://cl.ly/image/1t3c0Y2i1p0o

And my code:

```
drop: function(date) { // this function is called when something is dropped

                    // retrieve the dropped element's stored Event Object
                    var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');

                    // we need to copy it, so that multiple events don't have a reference to the same object
                    var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);

                    // assign it the date that was reported
                    copiedEventObject.start = date;

                    // render the event on the calendar
                    // the last `true` argument determines if the event "sticks" (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/)
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);

                    $(this).remove();                   

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by simply passing in the id that I needed via the ID attribute and then retrieving that within the code like so:

```
the_event_id = $( this ).attr('id');
copiedEventObject.id = the_event_id.replace('event_','');
```

Bypassing the data-event attribute completely.